# isspace() function return true even if the string doesn't contains any white-spaces character

Tags: c, string

I'm dealing with a client server application that work as follow:

1) Client read a string from stdin and send it to Server
2) Server check if string contains white-space, if not, then do something(not relevant), 
   otherwise do something else(not relevant).

```c
//i tested this function in other context and it works well 
int checkStr(char *x) {

    while(*x != '\0') {

        if(isspace(*x)) {

            return 1;
        }
    x++;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

The issue come when the function check a string from this:

```c
void read_cmd_line(char *buf) {
    printf("> ");
    fflush(stdout);
    memset(buf, '\0', BUFSIZE);
    if (read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUFSIZE) == -1) {
        perror("reading from stdin:");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the line read have a new-line character at the end? If that is not the problem, edit the question to show a [mre]. And do some basic debugging: When `isspace(*x)` is true, print the decimal value of `*x`, using `printf("isspace returns true for %d.\n", *x);`, and insert some code to count characters and show where in the string the character is (first, tenth, et cetera). Also print the whole string and all characters in it.

Comment: Is your `char` signed?

Comment: what do you see with your debugger? I mean what does *x have in it?

Comment: @EricPostpischil for debugging purpose i replaced the whitespace with another visible character and i see that the char is at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string `read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUFSIZE)` reads includes a new-line character at the end, and that is a white space character, so `isspace` correctly returns true (1).